# Grape JS in React : Default Blocks Showing Characters e.g. W, Q, E, R rather then icons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grapesjs

I am using Grapes JS news-letter editor in my project.

One issue I am facing here in the block section.

I am getting alphabet characters like Q, W, E, R in place of Icons by default.

here you can check on the right side block

https://grapesjs-react.thanhtunguet.info/?path=/story/editor--newslettereditor

required one => https://grapesjs.com/demo-newsletter-editor.html

Is there any default setting change so I can get the icons by default?
If not then how can I modify the letter icons into customized one

Answer (score 1):

it is the same without storybook ? some conflict with Font Awesome.

--- update ---

this work fine => https://github.com/thanhtunguet/grapesjs-react

Need relative path for font data (no loaded)

[image]

Comment: without storybook, it is showing the same as the storybook. Any workaround for FA?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else gets this, and ends up here without a clear answer:

I had this issue, after downloading the raw CSS + JS files from unpkg - the exact same files worked fine when running from the CDN, but I got the same error when pointing at them locally.

I resolved this by browsing the unpkg folders (https://unpkg.com/browse/grapesjs@0.17.25/dist/) - the grapes.js files is in the root, with two folders called "css" and "fonts". The issue with icons not loading is probably caused by not having the font files downloaded, and the CSS not pointing correctly (as the path in the CSS files are looking at a relative path).

So either get all the files and use the same folder-structure, or get the font files and edit the CSS to point at the right files.